# Return JavaScript from Rails Controller Action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a new Rails 7 application, I'm working on an autosave feature for a form with just a textarea. I use custom JavaScript to handle the form submission, and this works well.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  const form = document.querySelector(".form");
  const field = document.querySelector(".field");

  if (!form || !field) return;

  let submitTimeout;
  field.addEventListener("input", () => {
    clearTimeout(submitTimeout);

    submitTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      form.submit();
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

The ERB form is as follows (the @resource variable is always a persisted record, since it's set up that way in the `edit` action):

```
<%= form_with scope: :resource, model: @resource, remote: true, class: "form" do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :id %>
  <%= form.text_area :text, size: "30x10", class: "field" %>
<% end %>
```

However, when the form is submitted (behind the scenes), it calls the `update` action in my controller, which looks like so:

```rb
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def update
    resource = current_user.resources.find(resource_params.delete(:id))
    resource.update!(resource_params)
  end

  private

  ...
end
```

and this works well in most browsers, except when it comes to Safari. In Safari, the lack of response from this action confuses the browser and it shows a download link, which isn't the desired behaviour.

To get around this, I thought it would be useful to return some JavaScript, which I've seen elsewhere (on StackOverflow), so I updated the controller to respond to `js` and updated the form to use the `js` request format type:

```
<%= form_with scope: :resource, model: @resource, remote: true, format: :js, class: "form" do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :id %>
  <%= form.text_area :text, size: "30x10", class: "field" %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def update
    resource = current_user.resources.find(resource_params.delete(:id))
    resource.update!(resource_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  ...
end
```

and I created a sample JS file to test this setup in `/views/resources/update.js.erb`:

```js
console.log("hello world");
```

The issue is that after the response comes back, the browser redirects to `/resources/:id.js` where :id is the ID of the persisted resource. This is not the desired behaviour and not what I expected based on other questions and answers I've seen here. My intention, of course, is that the JavaScript is executed on the page. I figure it worked in older versions, but not in Rails 7. I'm on Rails 7.0.5, to be precise.

Comment: Quick question: have you checked that this works in previous version of rails?

Comment: @Jad no, I haven't checked that, but I later had similar issues with Turbo Streams, even after following a basic tutorial which uses Rails 7, so I'm no longer sure that the issue is and I've reverted this autosave feature for now anyway.